# I'm generating a basic form using JS; How can I get the data?

Tags: javascript, dom

I've got a basic javascript form creation script right here

```
var loginDiv;
var loginForm;
var formUserInput;
var formUserPass;
var formSubmit;

loginDiv = document.createElement('div');
loginDiv.id = 'loginDiv';

loginForm = document.createElement("form");
loginForm.setAttribute('method', "post");
loginForm.setAttribute('action', 'JavaScript:doSomething()');

formUserInput = document.createElement("input");
formUserInput.setAttribute('type', "text");
formUserInput.setAttribute('name', "username");

formUserPass = document.createElement("input");
formUserPass.setAttribute('type', "text");
formUserPass.setAttribute('name', "password");

formSubmit = document.createElement("input");
formSubmit.setAttribute('type', "submit");
formSubmit.value = "Submit";

loginForm.appendChild(formUserInput);
loginForm.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
loginForm.appendChild(formUserPass);
loginForm.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
loginForm.appendChild(formSubmit);

loginDiv.appendChild(loginForm);

document.getElementById('game').appendChild(loginDiv);
```

my question is; How do I pass the values of the text-fields into the doSomething() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value out of each of your dom nodes individually like so:

```
formUserInput.value
```

Instead of using this:

```
loginForm.setAttribute('action', 'JavaScript:doSomething()');
```

You could bind an event handler like this:

```
loginForm.addEventListener("submit", function(){
    doSomething(formUserInput.value, formUserPass.value)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass it in as an object

```
Var formValues = { "username": document.getElementById(set an id).value, ... }
```

Then pass the form values in as an object. You can access them as formValues.username etc.

Edit: Nick's suggestion to put a listener on submit is more conventional, I still suggest putting them in one nice tight object and pass it there.